# Is it programmer responsibility to delete temp file

Tags: android

Currently, I have an application, which will save a temporary screenshot, and let user share it through facebook. The image saving code is more or less as follow.

```
// Use external cache dir, as our image file is large (>1M)
File outputDir = this.getExternalCacheDir();
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("CHEOK", "CHEOK", outputDir);
// In Desktop's J2SE, this file will automatically be deleted, once my desktop
// application quit. However, this is not the case for Android. My guess is, JVM
// is not terminated, even our Android application had quit.
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
```

I realize even I quit my Android application (By pressing system "back" button), the tempFile is still there even we are using `deleteOnExit`. My guess is that the JVM is not terminated yet.

May I know, is it our application programmer responsibility, to delete the created temp file, during Activity's `onDestroy`? If not, what is the common best practice?

Comment: I think the reason it's not been triggered caused by how Android manage memories, a back button won't really kill the app but leave it in memory but just not active. My android phone SD card space always get smaller as lots of apps does not delete any cache/temp files, not sure why but I think it's better to delete them once you do not need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK yes, it's your responsibility to delete files not needed anymore (be they temporary or not). OS cannot know how long your app will be using that file.

Comment: can i assume the file will remain as long as the app is running, even if other apps also run and create their own temporary files ?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that.

Comment: can you please show a reference to this ? also, i've made a post about it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942700/do-temporary-files-get-deleted-even-while-the-app-is-running

Answer (score 1):

Its upto each and every application to keep the house (or rather the device) clean. :)

That being said

- The JVM is always running as far as android is booted up and running. So the file should get deleted if the device is restarted.
- There is good chance that the user will get offended if an app is leaving temporary files even when the app has been closed.

So close the temporary file yourself, when you are done with it. Need not even be until the app exits!